# What is the difference between the Chantry Garden and the Herb Garden upgrade in Skyhold?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I want to upgrade the garden in Skyhold, but the descriptions are a bit too vague for me. The chantry garden upgrade is described to bring "a potential resource gain from the inspired, including gold from tithes" and the herb garden "allows more herbs to be harvested".

I'd like to know how exactly the two options differ in the end.

If I choose the chantry garden:
- Can I still grow herbs, and if so, how many?
- What exactly is the "potential resource gain" and how frequent and useful is it (Do you get rare upgrade material or just commong things like iron)?
- How frequently and in what amount do you get the money from tithes?

If I choose the herb garden:
- How many herbs can I grow there?
- Do they grow faster, or is there any other herb growing advantage compared to the chantry garden?
- Does it offer any other advantages?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can find this information on the Dragon Age wiki on the "[Major Upgrades](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Major_Upgrades)" page.

If you choose the Herb garden :

- you have six pots instead of two to grow your plants, meaning you can grow up to six at the same time
- they do not grow faster nor is there any other advantage over the Chantry garden ; though if you craft a lot of potions or want to go for the Botanist achievement (harvesting 50 plants from Skyhold garden), it is much more convenient
- you get a codex entry for Skyhold Garden

If you choose the Chantry garden :

- you keep your two herb pots, meaning you can still grow herbs, only slower
- you get a Chantry Banner crown
- you get a codex entry for Skyhold Garden

  The "resource gain from the inspired" and "gold from tithes" refer to three war table missions that get unlocked:
- a War Table operation called "The Archive of Montfort", which rewards you with a Masterwork Balanced Pommel (reward info found on [SegmentNext](http://segmentnext.com/2014/11/27/dragon-age-inquisition-war-table-operations-and-missions-guide-tips-rewards-how-to-unlock/2/), not the wiki) and is faster when completed by Josephine
- a War Table operation called "[Tithe of the Faithful](http://dragonage3.wiki.fextralife.com/General+Missions+Guide)"
- a War Table operation called "[Eyes of the Maker](http://dragonage3.wiki.fextralife.com/Eyes+of+the+Maker)", which rewards you with a Gold Bracelet

Despite that, the upgrade is mostly a cosmetic one. The benefits gained from one or the other garden are minimal at best.

Comment: While I was looking for the SegmentNext source you mentioned (did I find the right link?), I found out a bit more about the tithes, although there is not much information about it and I added it so that we have one full answer. Many people suggest getting gold is a cut feature, but I assume the "Tithe of the Faithful" operation will get you a gold reward. I don't know if it's repeatable and what you actually get, so if anyone knows: feel free to change my edit.

Comment: @Kodama Despite the good intention, it is usually better to let the answerer edit his post himslef rather than editing it yourself. In those situation just request an edit with the information you'd like to have added in the answer :)

Comment: @WizLiz I think the remark that there was supposed to be a mechanism for gold tithes was wrong and I just thought it would be good to have the answer complete before I award the bounty. But I'll keep it in mind not to change too much :)

Comment: @WizardLizard I think not... http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120583/135956

Answer (score 4):

There are certain game options only available to an Inquisitor that embraces being a religious figure (for example, being able to convince the Grey Warden Ser Ruth to accept forgiveness in the Skyhold Judgement). The Chantry Garden war table missions are one such option.

If you have the Chantry garden and are a "faithful" Inquisitor, you will unlock a few war table missions. If you're not "faithful" (you've said in conversation you weren't saved by divine intervention etc) those missions won't unlock even if you have the Chantry upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The Herb garden gives you 6 pots to grow herbs. The Chantry garden gives you 2 pots for herbs. They grow at the same speed.

This is all the information I've been able to discover by playing. I have not seen any reference any "resource gain" by playing.

Comment: After clocking about 200 hours to this game on one playthrough, I haven't seen a single thing happen as a result of having the Chantry garden, and I haven't gained any additional resources as a result, despite what the Garden upgrade description states.

Answer (score 0):

> If choose the chantry garden:
>   - Can I still grow herbs, and if so, how many?

Yes you still can grow herbs from the 2 pots. (1 in each pot)

> What exactly is the "potential resource gain" and how frequent and useful is it (Do you get rare upgrade material or just commong things like iron)?

It's suppose to give gold from followers, but I have found no way to get that gold ...

> - How frequently and in what amount do you get the money from tithes?

See last answer ...

> If I choose the herb garden:
>   - How many herbs can I grow there?

You pass from 2 pots to 6 pots.

> - Do they grow faster, or is there any other herb growing advantage compared to the chantry garden?

Not that I noticed...

> - Does it offer any other advantages?

There is an achievement to gather 50 herbs in the herb garden in one playthrough.

-EDIT- 
It is not needed to have the Herbs garden for this achievement, but it is way easier with 6 pots.

[Reference Link](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/524897-skyhold-garden-chantry-upgrade/)

I would go with the Herbs Garden, but you can still choose. Have fun!

Comment: Are you sure the achievement only counts herbs grown in the herb garden pots, and not the chantry garden pots? (Obviously it's easier with more pots...)

Comment: @cbirdsong True, I just checked and its : "Harvest 50 herbs from Skyhold's garden in a single playthrough." So no it's not impossible with the chantry garden, but much longer.